# What causes 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON' when accessing Next.js admin at http://localhost:3000/admin?

Tags: arrays, json, next.js, schema, sanity

I have been following a tutorial on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcTPaUfay5I) and I am currently at the 1:07:02 mark. The tutorial is about creating a web application using Next.js and Sanity.io. I am encountering an issue where I am getting a SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 error when I try to access http://localhost:3000/admin.

It looks like this

error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()

Here is my code in the main website folder responsible for routing to the admin page

```
'use client';
import config from '@/sanity.config';
import { NextStudio } from 'next-sanity/studio';

export default function Adminpage() {
    return <NextStudio config={config} />;

}
```

Here is the code provided in the app.js of the sanity admin page

```
// This file is auto-generated on 'sanity dev'
// Modifications to this file is automatically discarded
import {renderStudio} from "sanity"
import studioConfig from "..\\..\\sanity.config.ts"

renderStudio(
  document.getElementById("sanity"),
  studioConfig,
  {reactStrictMode: false, basePath: "/"}
)
```

I have tried the solutions provided in the tutorial, including checking the CORS origins and verifying the JSON data being returned by the server. However, I am still unable to resolve the issue.

Can anyone suggest any other solutions or steps I can take to troubleshoot this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried the solutions provided in the tutorial, including checking the CORS origins and verifying the JSON data being returned by the server. However, I am still unable to resolve the issue.

Please let me know if there is another piece of code I should include, alot of it is default on the sanity admin page, and I reviewed most of it against a working project and it was the same

Comment: It is nearly impossible to provide help if you do not post your code.  Paste it into your question and format it between a pair of ``` ```, not an image.

Comment: The token "u" is indeed not valid for the first token in any JSON structure.  Is this JSON being fetched from a server in an AJAX request?  In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, what is the "JSON" data being returned from the server?  Or wherever this error is happening in the code, what is the "JSON" data being used?  The error is telling you that, whatever/wherever it is, it's not valid JSON.